# Broadcast and on not working as desired

Tags: angularjs, angular-broadcast

I am trying to broad cast from 1 controller and watch for that variable on another controller and expecting some changes on the second controller. But its not working.

Below is the first controller code

```
$scope.gotoKBPage = function()
      {
         $location.path('/kb');
         $rootScope.$broadcast('newVar',{id: "123"});
      };
```

Below is the second controller code which is the /kb page

```
  $scope.newPage = function()
  {
      $scope.pernotes     = true; // this makes a section visible, but not happening
  };

   $rootScope.$on('newVar', function(event, data)
   {
    if(data)
    {
        $scope.newPage();
    }
   });
```

Is there anything i need to do explicitly for this to take effect.

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: @ved - scope value does not change.

Comment: are you talking about $scope.newPage('id',data.id);?

Comment: @ved - yes same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $scope.newPage = function()
  {  
       $scope.$apply();
       $scope.pernotes     = true; // this makes a section visible, but not happening
  }
```

EDIT:
i have tested. It should work without $apply too.
Check this link:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19156/)

Comment: Your feedly is not exactly the same, you are omitting `$location.path()` and doing everything in the same controller, which I think is an important part of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are using a wrong approach. If you only want to pass a parameter to the new controller, why not use a route parameter? See the example at the end of this [documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Note that in your code, you are registering the `$on` after you broadcast the message, so it is not going to work.

Comment: $on is working. But in $on i am trying to change scope variables, which is not working

Comment: The $on is correctly registered. And I don't understand how routeparameters could fit the problem ?

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood the question, but as I understand, he wants to redirect the user to a new view, and pass a value to its controller. Is it right? A route parameter is in my opinion the best choice for this.

Comment: I still believe that the `$broadcast` is not a good solution to this case, even with the negative vote to my answer :)